# datagrid binding not working for one datagrid but is for another

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid (image is below).

You will see in the row details there are 3 other datagrids. The bindings work for two of them but not one which is rather annoying.

The datagrid that isn't working is a) not showing a value for the column Sedol when it should be & b) doesn't allow me to edit or click into the cells. The object its bound to isn't null as the datagrid that is working is bound to the same object. I don't see why this datagrid binding isn't working?

**Class HoldingEQ**

Please note I have stripped out some of the code. The class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and all the properties have the

```
public class HoldingLogEQ : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {            
        public DateTime DateEffective
        {
            get
            {
                return _dateEffective;
            }
            set
            {
                _dateEffective = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DateEffective");
            }
        }
        public SecruityId Security
        {
            get
            {
                return _security;
            }
            set
            {
                _security = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Security");
            }
        }
        public double Ratio
        {
            get
            {
                return _ratio;
            }
            set
            {
                _ratio = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Ratio");                    
            }
        }            
        public List<FundUI> Funds
        {
            get
            {
                return _funds;
            }
            set
            {
                _funds = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Funds");
            }
        }
        public HoldingLogEQ NewHldLog
        {
            get
            {
                return _newHldLog;
            }
            set
            {
                _newHldLog = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NewHldLog");
            }
        }

        private DateTime _dateEffective;
        private SecruityId _security = new SecruityId();            
        private double _ratio;
        private List<FundUI> _funds;
        private HoldingLogEQ _newHldLog;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
```

**Class SecurityId**

```
public class SecurityId : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {            
        public string ISIN
        {
            get
            {
                return _isin;
            }
            set
            {
                _isin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ISIN");
            }
        }
        public string Sedol
        {
            get
            {
                return _sedol;
            }
            set
            {
                _sedol = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Sedol");
            }
        }
        public string BbergTicker
        {
            get
            {
                return _bbergTicker;
            }
            set
            {
                _bbergTicker = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BbergTicker");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _isin;
        private string _sedol;
        private string _bbergTicker;
    }
```

**Datagrid that's not working - the datagrid in the top right of the image**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.NewHldLog,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                                  
                              RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"  
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}" 
                              RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeaderNested}"
                              CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}" 
                              Background="Silver"
                              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                              Margin="50,5,5,0"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ISIN" Binding="{Binding Security.ISIN, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="75"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sedol" Binding="{Binding Security.Sedol, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="75"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ticker" Binding="{Binding Security.Ticker, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="75"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Security.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="200"/>                                            
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

**Datagrid that is working**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.NewHldLog.Funds,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"                                                                  
                              RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"  
                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}" 
                              RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeaderNested}"
                              CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}" 
                              Background="Silver"
                              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                              Margin="50,5,5,20"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fund Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="75"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fund Code SS" Binding="{Binding CodeSS}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="75"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nominal" Binding="{Binding ChangeInNominal}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

**Image**

[image: Example of datagrid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datagrids expect to be bound to some form of collection. In your grid which is working you can see that it is bound to a List whereas the other grid is being bound to a single object.

Try changing it to a collection, or if its meant to only be 1 item then perhaps consider an alternative control to display it?

Comment: still doesn't work by changing it to a list & it also makes the other (working one) also not work. I don't quite follow why that is. What you said about the grid expects some collection makes sense. So I would at worse expect the top grid to be working even if the bottom one isn't

Comment: i'm not sure why you'd change the one that was already working? It was already bound to a property which is a list. Which property did you turn into a list? i'd expect the NewHldLog to now be a list exactly like the Funds property

Comment: I didn't change the datagrid that was already working. I changed the property NewHldLog from HoldingEQ to List<HoldingEQ>. NewHldLog has a property called Funds which the bottom datagrid was bound to

Comment: however I think you're correct about using an alternative control